# How can I change values of two specific key of multidimensional array in php dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am newbie in the PHP and love to learn PHP, so if this question is appeared as vogue please let me know. I want to change the value of `key1` and `key2` dynamically. I have an array such as..

```
$c = array(
    array(
        'key1'  => 'One',
        'key2'  => 'Two',
        'key3'  => 'val3' 
    ),
    array(
        'key1'  => 'Three',
        'key2'  => 'Four',
        'key3'  => 'val4'
    )
);
```

Say I want to replace the `$c[0]['key1']` and `$c[0]['key2']`(this way will be applied for other inner arrays means`$c[1]['key1']...`) values dynamically. The value will be coming dynamically as either an array or something else which fits best. But one condition is that the `key3` value will not be changed, it will remain what it is now.

Basically my expected result will be as..

```
$c = array(
    array(
        'key1'  => 'newval1',
        'key2'  => 'newval2',
        'key3'  => 'va3' 
    ),
    array(
        'key1'  => 'newval4',
        'key2'  => 'newval5',
        'key3'  => 'two'
    )
);
```

In here the new values should come automatically by iterating or by looping through so that I do not need hard coded. Actually I tried `array_combine` function through `foreach` loop but no result as expected.

Any suggestion please? If there is better way please share with me.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are these newval1, newval2, newval4 etc being generated? Is there another array containing these values to overwrite? Please clarify this first.

Comment: if the new value is of this type of array `$a = array('a' => 'newval1', 'b' => 'newval2')` , that would be great.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Do you want every key1 = newval1 and key2 as newval2?? You gotta state your intention and your desired output clearly.

Comment: Actually every `key1` and `key2` will get new value. Say first `key1` will newval1 and then second key1 will get another newval2, and by this way every key2 will get new value. Not the same value. Every loop those key will get new value. But no change of key3 value.I think it makes sense.

Comment: So what are these new values are? Where are you storing them, it these new values are still in mind, you have to create an array of new value with code. Then there're not a lot to do.

Comment: Could it be that you are just looking for something as simple as `$i=0; $c[$i]['key1']='newval1';`

Comment: yes, I am looking for that. In every iteration key1 will get new value. The new value will come automatically that is stored in an array. Just change the key1 value. @Chris